# mysql select from where different

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select a list of entries, but need to skip those that have matching fields in 2 different tables.
Here's my DB structure

orders:

```
| orders_id | customers_id | 
| 100       | 01           |
| 101       | 20           |
| 102       | 32           |
| 103       | 48           |
| 104       | 99           |
```

customers (for reference only):

```
| firstname | lastname | customers_id |
| John      | Doe      | 20           |
| Fred      | Flinty   | 22           |
| Mark      | Smith    | 32           |
```

testimonials:

```
| customers_id | testimonial |
| 20           | aaa         |
| 32           | bbb         |
| 38           | ccc         |
| 49           | ddd         |
| 55           | eee         |
```

So, I need to select all customers who are in my Orders table, but need to skip them if they are in my Testimonials table. In the example shown above, I would need to select only customers 01, 48 and 99 because they don't exist in Testimonials table.

This is what I tried, but am obviously missing something:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.customers_id, o.orders_id, 
       o.customers_id, s.date_added as status_date
FROM (orders o, testimonials t )
JOIN customers c
ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id
JOIN  status_history s
ON s.orders_id = o.orders_id
  and s.orders_status_id = o.orders_status
  and o.customers_id != t.customer_id
  order by o.orders_id ASC;
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to skip customers that are found in both tables (orders and testimonials)?
I feel I'm on the right track because, if I change the `and o.customers_id != t.customer_id` to `and o.customers_id = t.customer_id` I get only the customers that are in both tables (in this case, 20 and 32).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy way.

```
select c.* from order as o
join customers as c on o.customers_id = c.customers_id
where o.customers_id not in(select customers_id from testimonials)
```

Comment: @J W's answer has a faster query. Using `JOIN` is better than using `IN`.

Answer (score 4):

You can `LEFT JOIN` on this.

The reason for using `LEFT JOIN` is because it will show all records from the table defined on *lefthand side* whether it has a matching record or not on the table define on the *righthand side*. When table `Orders` is joined with table `testimonials`, all the records that have no match will have a value of null for the columns in the `testimonials` table and that's the one you are looking for. To filter out, we only need to get records with `NULL` value by checking the column with `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    orders a
        LEFT JOIN testimonials c
            ON a.customers_ID = c.customers_ID
        LEFT JOIN customers b
            ON a.customers_ID = b.customers_ID
WHERE   c.customers_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10467/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added some info on the mismatched customer*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5d9e/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

Adding up `INDEX`.

If on the real database the `Orders` table as well as `Testimonials` are always dependent on `Customers` table, then a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint should be enforce to *preserve referential integrity*.

Here's how:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders ADD CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 
    FOREIGN KEY (Customers_ID) REFERENCES Customers(Customers_ID);
ALTER TABLE Testimonials ADD CONSTRAINT tb_fk2
    FOREIGN KEY (Customers_ID) REFERENCES Customers(Customers_ID);
```

Comment: thank you for the great explanation, but I get no results (allowed memory exhausted...) when using this method, yet the solution from Neo seems to work just fine. Thank you for the efforts!

Comment: you have no index defined on the tables right? without that it will perform full table scan on the database causing it to exhaust on large databases.

Comment: I think you're right, no index defined on those tables. And yes, the DB is quite large... oh well, as long as there are no downsides to Neo's solution, I'm happy with it

Comment: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)

Comment: you will be unhappy soon if your database gets bigger and bigger.